# FindPkgConfig with set_target_properties is unusable for setting CFLAGS/LDFLAGS

Tags: build, cmake, pkg-config

`pkg_check_modules` from FindPkgConfig gives `MYLIBRARY_LDFLAGS` and `MYLIBRARY_CFLAGS` that are ordinary CMake lists (with semicolon-separator).

The `set_target_properties` and `set_property` accept just one string.

So that doesn't work because it doesn't expand the list:

```
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS ${MYLIBRARY_LDFLAGS})
```

This gives same thing with the semicolons inside:

```
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS "${MYLIBRARY_LDFLAGS}")
```

`set_target_properties` expands into multiple strings when unquoted and into one string with semicolons when quoted.

How am I supposed to use that?

Answer (score 4):

Common workflow with libraries searched by pkg-config within CMake:

```
# Use pkg-config for search library `xxx`.
pkg_check_modules(XXX xxx)

# Build target which uses given library

# The only command which has no target-oriented equivalent.
# But see comments after the code.
link_directories(${XXX_LIBRARY_DIRS}) 

# Two global commands belows can be replaced by target-oriented equivalent
# after creation of the target.
include_directories(${XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_compile_options(${XXX_CFLAGS_OTHER})

# Create target
add_executable(my_exe ...) # Or add_library()

# The only target-oriented command, which has no global equivalent.
target_link_libraries(my_exe ${XXX_LDFLAGS_OTHER}) # It is OK to have link flags here
target_link_libraries(my_exe ${XXX_LIBRARIES}) # Can be combined with previous call.
```

Note, that we use `XXX_LDFLAGS_OTHER` variable instead of `XXX_LDFLAGS` one. This is because `XXX_LDFLAGS` *includes* `-l` and `-L` options for which CMake has more suitable commands. Similar reason about usage of `XXX_CFLAGS_OTHER`.

---

Currently, CMake doesn't recommend to use [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html) command but use absolute paths to libraries in [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) call. One can extract absolute paths to libraries, listed by pkg-config, with use of [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) command:

```
...
# Instead of using `link_directories`, collect absolute paths to libraries.
set(XXX_LIBS_ABSOLUTE)
foreach(lib ${XXX_LIBRARIES})
    # Choose name of variable, which will contain result of `find_library`
    # for specific library.
    set(var_name XXX_${lib}_ABS)
    # Search library under dirs, returned by pkg-config.
    find_library(${var_name} ${lib} ${XXX_LIBRARY_DIR})
    list(APPEND XXX_LIBS_ABSOLUTE ${${var_name}})
endforeach()

# Instead of `target_link_libraries(my_exe ${XXX_LIBRARIES})`
target_link_libraries(my_exe ${XXX_LIBS_ABSOLUTE})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is how it is intended to be used, but this should work:

```
string(REPLACE ";" " " MYLIBRARY_LDFLAGS "${MYLIBRARY_LDFLAGS}")
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} APPEND_STRING PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS " ${MYLIBRARY_LDFLAGS}")
```

The `string(REPLACE)` command will change the list in a string separated by spaces, and that you can therefore use for the `LINK_FLAGS` property

The prepended white space in `" ${MYLIBRARY_LDFLAGS}"` and the `APPEND_STRING` instead of `APPEND` will ensure that the resulting string is usable as `LINK_FLAGS` even if the property is not empty.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, basic things must work without the hacks.

Comment: @Velkan: "Basic thing" is to have `LINK_FLAGS` (and `COMPILE_FLAGS`) *space-separated*. But you generate them as semicolon-separated. That is why you need `string(REPLACE)` operation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, FindPkgConfig generates them semicolon-separated.

Comment: @Velkan: Oops, sorry. I note origin of variables in your question only now.

Comment: "the point" is `How am I supposed to use that?`, so that's how you are supposed to use a semicolon-separated list for a property that accepts a space-separated list.