# How to configure DBus dependencies with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, dbus

I am new to CMake and DBus. I am following along the guide [here](http://linoxide.com/how-tos/d-bus-ipc-mechanism-linux/) and make a basic program compile and execute.

The first problem that I ran into was my program will not find

```
<dbus/dbus.h>
```

I got around that issue by adding some include directories to my CMakeList.txt.
Currently, my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
...

include_directories(/usr/lib/)
include_directories(/usr/include/dbus-1.0/)
include_directories(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include)
include_directories(/usr/include/glib-2.0)
include_directories(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/)

set (LIBS
  dbus-1
  dbus-glib-1
)

add_executable(mydbus mydbus.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mydbus ${LIBS} )
```

Now, my program is complaining about not being able to find dbus-arch-deps.h

```
/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h:29:33: fatal error: dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h: No such file or directory
 #include <dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h>
```

I know that the solution for this is to use proper command line flags or pkg-config. As discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40763/symlink-for-dbus-headers) and numerous other posts.

However, I do not know how to configure CMakeLists.txt to have similar effect.

My guess would be to add something like find_package(dbus-1) to CMakeLists.txt. And if that is correct, I am going to have to write my own Finddbus-1.cmake. Does this sound correct? Or is there an easier way?

I will appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may get an existing `FindDBus.cmake` script (e.g., [this one](https://github.com/adobe/webkit/blob/master/Source/cmake/FindDBus.cmake)), copy it into your project, and use as

```
find_package(DBus REQUIRED)
# Use results of find_package() call.
include_directories(${DBUS_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(mydbus mydbus.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mydbus ${DBUS_LIBRARIES})
```

Alternatively, as you know `pkgconfig` can find DBus, you may use CMake module [PkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html). Actually, `FindDBus.cmake` script, referenced above, uses *PkgConfig* module in its implementation. Possible usage could be:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED) # Include functions provided by PkgConfig module.

pkg_check_modules(DBUS REQUIRED dbus-1) # This calls pkgconfig with appropriate arguments
# Use results of pkg_check_modules() call.
include_directories(${DBUS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${DBUS_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(mydbus mydbus.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mydbus ${DBUS_LIBRARIES})
```

However, using `link_directories` is not recommended, it is better to use absolute paths to libraries in `target_link_libraries()` call. That is why it is better to combine `pkg_check_modules` with `find_library`, as it is done in the referenced `Find` script. [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35476270/3440745) describes generic way for use result of pkgconfig in CMake.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. Unfortunately, that solution did not work for me. The CMake stage goes well and it generates a Makefile. However, when I do make, that's when I get that error. I tried including /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/dbus, because that's where this file is. But I still get the error.

Comment: The files is included as `<dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h>`, so include path shouldn't contain trailing `dbus` subdirectory. BTW, what is an exact path to the header `dbus-arch-deps.h` on you machine?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That suggestion seems to have worked. In addition, I had to include directory path for glibconfig.h as well. I am just wondering though.. am I doing things the right way? As in, depending on the complexity of the program, there could be dozens of header file dependencies. And in my case find_package(PkgConfig) did not help. So, how do I configure my CMake to achieve the same behavior as if I was doing something like `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` on the command line?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more detailed examples about searching DBus with `find_package()` and `pkg_check_modules`. `pkg_check_modules` can be applied also for glib-2.0, this will have an effect of *pkg-config*.