# CMake glibconfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, gstreamer, glib

I am coding a simple GStreamer application and I have encountered an error with glibconfig.h. I am using CLion with CMake in order to set up the environment.
My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
include(FindPkgConfig)
project(NDNvideo)

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lib/pkgconfig")

find_package(PkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(GST REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0>=1.4
    gstreamer-sdp-1.0>=1.4
    gstreamer-video-1.0>=1.4
    gstreamer-app-1.0>=1.4)


include_directories(${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS}/gst)

add_executable(NDNvideo VideoFramer.cpp)
target_compile_options(NDNvideo PUBLIC ${GST_FLAGS})
target_link_libraries (NDNvideo ${GST_LIBRARIES})
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glibconfig.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I've tried linking GLib alongside with GStreamer library but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Where is the file `glibconfig.h` located? Is it in the folder that you added to the include directories?

Comment: @drescherjm It is located in gstreamer folder in lib/include/glib-2.0 . I've used pkg-config to set up libraries. It has both gstreamer-1.0 and glib-2.0

Comment: That probably does not match `${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS}/gst`

Comment: @drescherjm if i remove /gst it returns me an error  `cannot find -lgstreamer-1.0`

Comment: The variable `GST_INCLUDE_DIRS` is most likely a **list of directories**, not a single directory. So appending `/gst` to the variable's value has a little sence. Why do not simply call `include_directories(${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS})`?

Comment: That is a completely different problem.

Comment: The error `cannot find -lgstreamer-1.0` means that you don't adjust link directories. These directories are contained in `GST_LIBRARY_DIRS` variable, as described in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FindPkgConfig.html). See that my answer about using results of  `pkg_check_modules`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35476270/3440745